# What's another word for "unrelated people living together"?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

What's a word to refer to **unrelated** people living in the same house? By this, I mean that they are not spouses or blood-related.

Basically what's the "house" version of "room-mates"?

I've thought of "cohabitant", "coresident", or even "housemate" but these words give the connotation that the persons involved are *related*.

Comment: Housemates are quite common around here. I don't infer any particular relationship from that, beyond living together. Why do you think it has that connotation?

Comment: Yes, *housemate* is the term you want.

Comment: *Housemate* certainly does not connote relationship. In the US, *roommate* and *housemate* are increasingly used interchangeably. If you want a more formal term, *cotenant* fits the bill if the person shares lessee responsibilities.

Comment: @BraddSzonye, (2) of http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/housemate

Comment: Strange, I've never heard it used that way, and clearly neither have the other folks commenting. Didn't see anything in the other dictionaries I checked either. Dictionary.com might be in error here.

Comment: Note that even Urban Dictionary doesn't mention _housemate_ as a euphemism for “partner.” (Although there is a joke entry using _housemate_ as a verb meaning to mate with your housemate, I wouldn't take it seriously.)

Comment: BlessedGeek, I've rolled back your edit as it changed the meaning of the question in a way that contradicts the accepted answer. Please ask (or at least notify) the OP when making such edits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [*roommate, housemate, flatmate*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roommate) and similar terms to indicate that two unrelated people live together. None of these words imply any particular relationship (unlike [*cohabitation,*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohabitation) which suggests that they have a sexual relationship or partnership).

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roommate) notes a usage difference between American and UK English:

> In the UK, the term “roommate” means a person living in the same bedroom, whereas in the United States and Canada, “roommate” and “housemate” are used interchangeably regardless whether a bedroom is shared. This article uses the term “roommate” in the US sense of a person one shares a residence with who is not a relative or significant other.

Thus, you can use *housemate* anywhere to indicate that two people simply live in the same house. In American English, you can also call them *roommates.*

Comment: What about "cotenant"?

Comment: I've never heard _cotenant_ used in conversation. It might be OK for formal writing but otherwise it would sound stilted to me. _Roommate_ or _housemate_ is far more common, probably even in formal writing.

Answer (score 0):

Room renters or bedroom renters is the best term I can think of that describes the individuals who respond to “roommate wanted” ads advertising a bedroom available in an apt occupied by other unconnected individuals who have also moved into the other bedrooms as strangers to each other.

This has become a common practice in the larger cities. If I had to guess I would say NYC was the first place that I knew of that normalized this practice. My daughter lived in a one bedroom apt in NYC with her college sweetheart once graduated from college. When they broke up both of them rented bedrooms within apts with other bedroom renters all unknown to each other.
“Bedroom renters”. BTW the landlord usually rents the apt as an apt and not by the bedroom. It’s the occupants that rent out bedrooms to cover the fixed monthly rent.

Comment: Welcome!  It looks like the OP is asking for one word for this.  I hope you stick around to take the site [tour] 
 and familiarize yourself with the [help].