# Does “housemate” imply a sexual relationship?

Tags: meaning, slang

In [a recent question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/133760/whats-another-word-for-unrelated-people-living-together), another user expressed concern that *housemate* has sexual connotations because of this definition at [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/housemate):

> ***noun***
>   1. a person with whom one shares a house or other residence.
>   2. a sexual partner with whom one shares a house or other living quarters without being married.

However, I have never heard or seen the word used in that second sense. I would normally expect the a term like [*domestic partner*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domestic_partnership) or [*cohabitation*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/cohabit) to express that meaning, not *housemate.* Furthermore, I could not find another dictionary with a similar sense of the word. Only [*Urban Dictionary*](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=housemate) has a related entry, which appears to be a joke and not a serious report of usage (“My friend just housemated with my fellow housemate”).

Is the Dictionary.com entry spurious, or is the “sexual partner” sense of *housemate* in actual use? If so, is it regional or perhaps euphemistic?

Comment: The word "friend" ***can*** imply a sexual relationship in the right circumstances. So can "housemate". But usually, neither of them do.

Comment: Agreed on all counts, which is why I suspect that the sense in the Dictionary.com entry is spurious.

Comment: **Roommate** is much more common than housemate and even with roommates, if I met someone who has a roommate, I would not know the state of that relationship without other clues, such as meeting the roommate and observing the interaction between the two, whether they shared a bedroom or had separate bedrooms, other "significant others", etc.  I think housemate could be used either way, platonically or to refer to an unmarried sexual partner.

Comment: @Kristina Lopez: So far as I know, *roommate* is just an American term for *person I share[d] a room with in college student accommodation*. I own my own house - in consideration of which, the person I share it with pays rent. We refer to each other as *housemates* (we share several rooms, but certainly *not* our personal bedrooms or bathrooms) because it's more accurate than saying we're landlord and tenant/lodger.

Comment: @FumbleFingers American usage of _roommate_ is for any people living together, regardless of age or housing type. UK usage is quite different.

Comment: Well, OED defines **housemate** as *A person who lives in a house or building with another or several others, esp. (in later use) as tenants in a shared house. Also fig.* And **roomate** as *orig. N. Amer. A person occupying the same room, flat, **or house** as another.* I guess that *or house* bit is where US/UK meanings part company.

Comment: @BraddSzonye I (in Chicago) have adopted "flatmate" because of the ambiguity (and I work with Londoners), when I was sharing an apartment with the same person I used to room with in college.  I sometimes wish others would do the same...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It certainly does not have any such meaning to me (in England); indeed I would take to to imply that the people were not in a relationship, though that implication might be overturned by other evidence.

Comment: Yes cisatlantically, too. Some would characterize it as an [implicature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicature) rather than an implication.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly how I understand the word too. I'll allow some time to see whether anyone has contradictory evidence.

Comment: @StoneyB: I agree, but I don't know a verb that conveys the idea of implicature as opposed to implication. _Implicate_ means something different.

Comment: @ColinFine I've seen *implicate* used this way, and I don't like it any  more than you do. In context, *imply* vs *entail* works.